# Project structure for Rust (local dependencies)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Rust project structured as below

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src/
│   ├── main.rs
│   └── framework/
│      ├── pluginchain.rs
│   └── plugins/
│      ├── plugin.rs
```

There are more source files under both framework and plugins, but that's the gist of it. Each directory (framework, plugins) has a mod.rs file to include the assortment of rust source files in each directory. So from main.rs to include source from the framework directory, I can do below ..

```rust
mod framework;
use crate::framework::{pluginchain, ...}
```

And using other source in framework is no problem. Declare in any of the source in framework.

```rust
use crate::framework::{...}
```

Now problem I'm running into is how to use something from plugins directory in the framework directory. I've tried a a variety of mod plugins .. use crate::plugins::{...} ... use super::plugins::[...} etc...

I'm stumped on how to do what I believe is probably pretty simple.

Comment: Ugh, formatting of directory structure not working.

under src/ there is main.rs and two directories 'framework' and 'plugins'
under framework and plugins there are rust source. Each directory also has a mod.rs declaring each pub mod <source>
I'm trying to make visible source from plugins to framework

Comment: Does it fail because the module is not found, or because the resources are private? Could you show an error message?

Answer (score -1):

(It is lack of `main.rs` in your product, but) It might be following:

```
mod framework;
mod plugin;
```

To call `crate::plugin::somewhat` from `crate::framework`, change module visibility to `pub(crate)`:

```
mod framework;
pub(crate) mod plugin;
```

This only changes module visibility, you should also change member visibility under the module.